# React - embed application in existing page (sub folder in web server)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a React application that I built, generated the following files:

[image]

I'm trying to add this app to an existing web page, so I created a new page with the following content:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/duel-arena/assets/vendor.280c86f1de98563a3339.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/duel-arena/assets/app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I placed the app JS and assets in the `components/duel-arena` folder.

When I'm trying to load my app, I get the following errors:

```
app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1 GET http://localhost/5.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
l.e @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
./src/index.js @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
1 @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1 GET http://localhost/assets/5.87b190c482f47b4374bd.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
l.e @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
./src/index.js @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
1 @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1 GET http://localhost/4.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
l.e @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
./src/index.js @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
1 @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1 GET http://localhost/assets/4.49d3cfaa7b81bae88c40.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
l.e @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
./src/index.js @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
1 @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:36786
l @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1
app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading CSS chunk 5 failed.
(./5.css)
    at HTMLLinkElement.n.<computed>.n.<computed>.<computed>.o.push.n.<computed>.f.onerror (app.280c86f1de98563a3339.js:1)
```

I tried to modify my react  history/router with the path, but no luck:

```
const renderApp = async Component => {
  const historyConfig = {
    basename: 'components/duel-arena/'
  };
  const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory(historyConfig);
  const routeStore = new RouterStore();
  const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, routeStore);

    render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Router history={history} basename={'/components/battle-arena'}>
                <Provider store={isProduction ? store : hotRehydrate()} routing={routeStore} >
                    <App />
                </Provider>
            </Router>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
};
```

Any idea what I'm; missing for my application to work in my web page?

Comment: Seems like your web server does not find your included js files.

Comment: have you checked this https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/ ?

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt This is on what the question about...

Comment: @M.Abdeldayem Yes, using `base href` works if you can change the `index.html` of your page, but I'm just trying to embed a component to an existing web page and I can't se the base href for all.